# Marker Clusterer in DevExtreme Mobile

Tags: mobile, markerclusterer, devextreme

I'm developing an application in DevExtreme Mobile. In application, I use DXMap in this application. How can I use the marker clusterer structure in DevExtreme Mobile App?

Comment: What do you mean `the marker clusterer structure`?

Comment: http:// android.amberfog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/utility-markercluster.png. There is example in this picture. I want to make this process in Devextreme Mobile. How can I do ?

Comment: The `dxMap` widget doesn't support this functionality. But you can implement it yourself using only Google Maps(without dxMap). This [article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) describes hot to do it.

Comment: I don't use map without dxMap in Devextreme mobile app. I can try again to add maps without DXMap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps Marker Clusterer API to create and manage per-zoom-level clusters for a large number of DevExtreme dxMap markers. Here is an example:

[dxMap Marker Clusterer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T310385)

This example is based on the approach described in the Google [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en#markerclusterer) article

Here is sample code:

```
$("#dxMap").dxMap({
    zoom: 3,
    width: "100%",
    height: 800,
    onReady: function (s) {
        var map = s.originalMap;

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude, dataPhoto.longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }
});
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Please quote the example here, within your answer rather than *just* link to it. Others can't see the example later if the link changed.

Answer (score 0):

The kry is to use the google maps api. I did it for my app, here how.

This the html, very simple:

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'map', title: 'Punti vendita', pane: 'master', secure:true } ">
    <div data-bind="dxCommand: { id: 'back', behavior: 'back', type: 'back', visible: false }"></div>
        <div data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } ">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">


            <div data-bind="dxMap:options"></div> <!--this for the map-->

            <div id="large-indicator" data-bind="dxLoadIndicator: {height: 60,width: 60}" style="display:inline;z-index:99;" />
            <div data-bind="dxPopover: {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 'auto',
                    visible: visible,
                }">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page loads, the app read the gps coordinates:

```
function handleViewShown() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    jQuery("#large-indicator").css("display", "none"); //this is just a gif to indicate the user to wait the end of the operation
}
```

If the gps location is correctly read, I save the coordinates (the center of the map):

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    var lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon1 = position.coords.longitude;
    center([lat1, lon1]);
}
```

And these are the options I set to my dxMap:

```
options: {
    showControls: true,
    key: { google: "myGoogleApiKey" },
    center: center,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    zoom: zoom,
    provider: "google",
    mapType: "satellite",
    autoAdjust: false,
    onReady: function (s) {
        LoadPoints();
        var map = s.originalMap;
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < MyPoints().length; i++) {
            var data = MyPoints()[i];
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.location[0], data.location[1]);
            var marker = createMarker(latLng, data.title, map, data.idimp);
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { imagePath: 'images/m' });
    }
},
```

Where MyPoints is populated calling LoadPoints:

```
function LoadPoints() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: myApiUrl,
        success: function (Response) {
            var tempArray = [];
            for (var point in Response) {
                var location = [Response[p]["latitudine"], Response[p]["longitudine"]];
                var title = Response[p]["name"] + " - " + Response[p]["city"];
                var temp = { title: title, location: location, tooltip: title, onClick: GoToNavigator, idpoint: Response[p]["id"] };
                tempArray.push(temp);
            }

            MyPoints(tempArray);

        },
        error: function (Response) {
            jQuery("#large-indicator").css("display", "none");
            var mex = Response["responseText"];
            DevExpress.ui.notify(mex, "error");
        }
    });
}
```

Note that in the folder Myproject.Mobile/images I included the images m1.png, m2.png, m3.png, m4.png and m5.png.
You can found them [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/tree/gh-pages/images).

Comment: Also add this to your index.html file:    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/data.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>